# How to call a function from an array, which is in a class

Tags: php, arrays, class, function

My problem is this, i have a function which is stored in an array which is a part of a class. I want to call a function from this array using `call_user_func()` however i can't seem to figure out how to write this.

Calling a function from an array which is not in a class can be done like such.

```
 $thearray = array( 0 => 'funcone', 1 => 'functwo');
 call_user_func($thearray[0]);
```

However when i try to do this to an array which is in a class, it do sent work, i imagine because i need to reference the class somehow. I know that you can call a function from a class like this:

```
 call_user_func(array($myclass, 'funcone'));
```

But my question is how would a call a function from an array, which is within a class, by using `call_user_func()`; i hope somebody can help me with this, i have a feeling that it is just a matter of how its written.

Comment: Check `funcone` is public non static function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the array within the class is public, you can do:

```
call_user_func(array($myclass, $myclass->thearray[0]));
```

Did that answer your question?

*Update*:

I tried the following and it worked:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo "quux\n";
    }

    public $baz = array('bar');
}

$foo = new Foo();
call_user_func(array($foo, $foo->baz[0]));

shell$ php userfunc.php 
quux
```

Comment: does not work im afraid, i tried doing that before asking, it seems logical that it would, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @Alex Would you be able to describe your class structure?

Comment: its just a class i created for testing out weather i could call a function from an array within it, since i had a felling i might encounter trouble; it just has two public functions and a variable which has an array which holds the names of the two functions, like the one above.

Comment: @Alex I tried a sample program and it seemed to work. Hope that was your requirement.

Comment: Brilliant! it worked, you sir are brilliant, thank you very much, so it turned out to be a case of making the variable public, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
call_user_func(array($this, $thearray[0]));
```

http://codepad.org/lCCUJYLK

Comment: thats fine; but that was not my question, im trying to call a function that is within an array, which is in a class, like i showed above; not just a function that is within a class.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the idea. What do you mean saying 'function that is within an array'? If the $thearray is your private variable then just call it `$this->thearray[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Please bear with me as it's going to be a bit long. :)

Well, i think we can achieve this via PHP's `overloading` concept, which as most of you know is quite different from other object-oriented languages.

From the PHP manual's overloading page - `Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods one can establish in a class for various action types.` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

Much of this overloading magic is dependent of PHP's [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

If you see the list of magic methods, the one that can help us here is [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)

**The magic method __call will be called every time a non-existing class method is called.**

This will help us prevent throwing up any errors / set any custom messages. So, here is an example that we can use to solve the problem stated above.

```
<?php
class Test
{
    private $arr = array( 'funcone', 'functwo' );

    public function __call( $func_name, $func_args ) {
        echo "Method called: " . $func_name . "\n";
        echo "Arguments passed: " . $func_args . "\n";

        // this will call the desired function.
        call_user_func( array( $this, $this->arr[ $func_args ] ) );
    }
}

$obj = new Test;
// run the first function in the array
$obj->runTest(0);
?>
```

Hope that helps. If this doesn't work, i'm sure it can be tweaked with a little trial and error. ( Now, i am talking PHP, right? tweaks... ;) )

Comment: thank you for the detailed anwser, i was trying to call the functions outside of the class, @g13n answered the question for me; thank you anyways, this seems like an interesting approach.